# Requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress

We using server centos. Running my site, currently working home page itself, rest of page not working. Please help me

File Path
/var/www/html

Not Found
The requested URL /about-us/ was not found on this server. this error coming out.

.htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can login in wp-admin backend with credentials Administrator.

You need to be sure that the .htaccess file is editable

So, go in Settings -> Permalink, and refresh this (save without edit anything).

Another test:
I suggest return your permalink to default ( /?p=ID ) so you ensure that .htaccess is the problem.